# Change indentation of python script in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation, spyder

I have a very long python script.
I want to make some changes in it. But it uses 2 spaces indentation while I want to use **TAB** or **4 spaces** indentation.

I know how to change Indentations while writing a script.

> Tools >>> Preferences >>> Editor >>> Advanced settings >>> Indentation characters

But it's not working with existing scripts.

So how can I change the indentations to 4 spaces or TAB in my file?

**PS:** *For now I don't have other editors to work with. So I am stuck with spyder only.(and Notepad++)*

Comment: How about trying with replacing `"  "` (2 spaces) with `"    "` (4 spaces)? It might break some code formatting around if you have double spaces anywhere else in your code, but that should be easy to fix.

Comment: TBH the script has more than 1k lines. I don't wanna risk that before looking at other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1)

As suggested in the comment, just find-and-replace `"  "` (2 spaces) with `"    "` (4 spaces). This might replace double-spaces inside your code as well, but it's the simplest and quickest solution. Beware of hardcoded strings with double spaces, those will break.

### Solution 2)

Regexes! In a different script (or the console), run:

```
import re
with open('my_script_with_2_spaces.py') as fp:
  text = fp.read()

def gen_replacement_string(match):
  print(match)
  print(match.groups())
  return '    '*(len(match.groups()[0])//2)

with open('my_script_with_4_spaces.py', 'w') as fp:
  fp.write(re.sub(r'^((?:  )+)', gen_replacement_string, text, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

#### What does the regex do?

- `^` matches the beginning of the line (requires the `MULTILINE` flag)
- the outer `(...)` is needed to consider `...` (its content) as one group, so I can then  retrieve it easily (it's the `match.groups()[0]` in `gen_replacement_string`)
- the inner `(?:  )+` is a non-capturing group repated one-or-more times that matches two spaces

So, all in all I'll match all spaces-only strings with multiple-of-two length that appear at the beginning of a line. That's the indentation we want.

`re.sub` takes as a second parameter a function that I use to generate dynamically the replacement string, since we want it to have the same indentation depth as the original. This happens in `gen_replacement_string`.